# PostgreSQL: NOT IN versus EXCEPT performance difference (edited #2)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two queries that are functionally identical. One of them performs very well, the other one performs very poorly. I do not see from where the performance difference arises.

Query #1:

```
SELECT id 
FROM subsource_position
WHERE
  id NOT IN (SELECT position_id FROM subsource)
```

This comes back with the following plan:

```
                                  QUERY PLAN                                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on subsource_position  (cost=0.00..362486535.10 rows=128524 width=4)
   Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..2566.50 rows=101500 width=4)
           ->  Seq Scan on subsource  (cost=0.00..1662.00 rows=101500 width=4)
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT id FROM subsource_position
EXCEPT
SELECT position_id FROM subsource;
```

Plan:

```
                                           QUERY PLAN                                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SetOp Except  (cost=24760.35..25668.66 rows=95997 width=4)
   ->  Sort  (cost=24760.35..25214.50 rows=181663 width=4)
         Sort Key: "*SELECT* 1".id
         ->  Append  (cost=0.00..6406.26 rows=181663 width=4)
               ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=0.00..4146.94 rows=95997 width=4)
                     ->  Seq Scan on subsource_position  (cost=0.00..3186.97 rows=95997 width=4)
               ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..2259.32 rows=85666 width=4)
                     ->  Seq Scan on subsource  (cost=0.00..1402.66 rows=85666 width=4)
(8 rows)
```

I have a feeling I'm missing either something obviously bad about one of my queries, or I have misconfigured the PostgreSQL server. I would have expected this `NOT IN` to optimize well; is `NOT IN` always a performance problem or is there a reason it does not optimize here?

Additional data:

```
=> select count(*) from subsource;
 count 
-------
 85158
(1 row)

=> select count(*) from subsource_position;
 count 
-------
 93261
(1 row)
```

**Edit**: I have now fixed the A-B != B-A problem mentioned below. But my problem as stated still exists: query #1 is still massively worse than query #2. This, I believe, follows from the fact that both tables have similar numbers of rows.

**Edit 2**: I'm using PostgresQL 9.0.4. I cannot use EXPLAIN ANALYZE because query #1 takes too long. All of these columns are NOT NULL, so there should be no difference as a result of that.

**Edit 3**: I have an index on both these columns. I haven't yet gotten query #1 to complete (gave up after ~10 minutes). Query #2 returns immediately.

Comment: @mu is too short: that is exactly the problem. Different queries semantics. You should make that an answer

Comment: I've made the correction; please take another look.

Comment: You need to specify what version of PostgreSQL you're using. Also, I don't believe those queries are the same now either - consider the NULL value. And finally, you should always post EXPLAIN ANALYZE and not just plain EXPLAIN.

Comment: I've addressed your concerns as best as possible.

Comment: NOT IN is usually a bad idea in regards to performance in general. That might be the reason why PostgreSQL has the (probably proprietary as I have never heard of it in other RDBMS) EXCEPT. You did not say if queries actually take different time to execute or if it is just estimated cost (which may be pretty off). And what about indexes?

Comment: @Marian, thanks, you are the first person to offer something constructive. I haven't yet gotten query #1 to complete. Query #2 returns almost instantly. These are PK and FK columns, and I have an index on both.

Comment: @Marian FYI, MS SQL Server and IBM DB2 have EXCEPT and Oracle has MINUS. I'm guessing other databases have their equivalents too...

Comment: @Branko Yeah, you are right. I totally forgot about MINUS

Comment: Any other nonstandard config parameters? And what's the datatype of the columns?

Comment: I'm using the default configuration. They're integers.

Comment: Are the row estimates reasonable? If so, try bumping up work_mem on your queries, from the default 1mb maybe up to 20 or so just to test.

Comment: @Magnus: that fixed it! Please make this an answer so I can accept it, or elaborate, if there's more I need to do.

Comment: What happens if you try a LEFT JOIN version? Something like `select sp.id from subsource_position sp left join subsource s on sp.id = s.position_id where s.position_id is null`. Looks like it sees "select w/o where", goes straight to a sequential scan and materializes it because the intermediate result set is large. If you add a WHERE to the inner SELECT you'll see it transition from seq scan to index scan and to materialized at different points. Materialize looks like your enemy here.

Comment: That gives me a Hash Anti Join, which is something new I haven't seen before. It performs well, and does not seem to be dependent on the `work_mem` setting.

Comment: Hash anti-join is also dependent on work_mem, just in a different way.

Comment: Query 1 is slow because there is 2 masive operations for every line subsource_position. First for every line you do select, it will cache but still that cache must be reused for every line. Second for every line subsource_position you must check values in that list of subsource = dificulty: 85158*93261 ~ 8*10^9 ~ probably half 4*10^9 comparsions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are running with the default configuration, try bumping up work_mem. Most likely, the subquery ends up getting spooled to disk because you only allow for 1Mb of work memory. Try 10 or 20mb.

Comment: In my testing, values as low as 2 MB are sufficient to fix this problem for me. I'll probably use something in between. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The performance difference is not related to server configuration. Those two queries have different abilities (or restrictions) to use indexes. #1 => requires scanning all entries in subsource one by one, the #2 can get both indexes to "inter-match" (HASH JOIN).  But OK, adding more "work memory" for "scanning table in RAM" can help running very bad SQL not using junctions...

Answer (score 27):

Query #1 is not the elegant way for doing this... (NOT) IN SELECT is fine for a few entries, but it can't use indexes (`Seq Scan`).

Not having EXCEPT, the alternative is to use a JOIN (`HASH JOIN`):

```sql
    SELECT sp.id
    FROM subsource_position AS sp
        LEFT JOIN subsource AS s ON (s.position_id = sp.id)
    WHERE
        s.position_id IS NULL
```

EXCEPT appeared in Postgres long time ago... But using MySQL I believe this is still the only way, using indexes, to achieve this.

Comment: What a brilliant idea!

Answer (score 7):

Your queries are not functionally equivalent so any comparison of their query plans is meaningless.

Your first query is, in set theory terms, this:

```
{subsource.position_id} - {subsource_position.id}
          ^        ^                ^        ^
```

but your second is this:

```
{subsource_position.id} - {subsource.position_id}
          ^        ^                ^        ^
```

And `A - B` is not the same as `B - A` for arbitrary sets `A` and `B`.

Fix your queries to be semantically equivalent and try again.

Comment: I have corrected the SQL and the query plan. I'd appreciate it if you would take another look.

Comment: Wow, I had to read those about 5 times to see the difference in the positions of the "." and "_" characters.

Comment: @RossBradbury Does that little edit make it clearer?

Answer (score 4):

If `id` and `position_id` are both indexed (either on their own or first column in a multi-column index), then two index scans are all that are necessary - it's a trivial sorted-merge based set algorithm.

Personally I think PostgreSQL simply doesn't have the optimization intelligence to understand this.

(I came to this question after diagnosing a query running for over 24 hours that I could perform with `sort x y y | uniq -u` on the command line in seconds. Database less than 50MB when exported with pg_dump.)

PS: more interesting comment [here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/28345.1233241001@sss.pgh.pa.us):

> more work has been put into optimizing
>   EXCEPT and NOT EXISTS than NOT IN, because the latter is substantially
>   less useful due to its unintuitive but spec-mandated handling of NULLs.
>    We're not going to apologize for that, and we're not going to regard it as a bug.

What it comes down to is that `except` is different to `not in` with respect to null handling. I haven't looked up the details, but it means PostgreSQL (aggressively) doesn't optimize it.

Answer (score 2):

The second query makes usage of the `HASH JOIN` feature of postgresql. This is much faster then the `Seq Scan` of the first one.

Comment: Does this imply that 'not in' cannot use the index?