# Redshift EXCEPT much slower than LEFT JOIN

Tags: performance, left-join, amazon-redshift, database-performance, sql-except

I'm trying to compare a staging table ('new data') to another table ('existing data') to identify added/changed/removed rows, and eventually an upsert. This is an expensive operation - a full diff on a large dataset. I really wanted to use the `EXCEPT` command for syntactic clarity, but am having serious performance problems with it, and find a `LEFT JOIN` is much better.

The two tables have a similar number of rows and the same schema (almost - the 'second' table has an additional `created_date` column).

They both share `distkey(date)` and `sortkey(date, id1, id2)`; I'm even specifying the columns in the 'correct' order within the `EXCEPT` statement to help the optimizer.

The query plans for each, on a testing-sized subset of the data, are below.

```
explain
select date, id1, id2, id3, value, attr1, attr2, attr3 from new_data
except select date, id1, id2, id3, value, attr1, attr2, attr3 from existing_data;

XN SetOp Except  (cost=1000002817944.78..1000003266822.61 rows=1995013 width=1637)
  ->  XN Sort  (cost=1000002817944.78..1000002867820.09 rows=19950126 width=1637)
        Sort Key: date, id1, id2, id3, value, attr1, attr2, attr3
        ->  XN Append  (cost=0.00..399002.52 rows=19950126 width=1637)
              ->  XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=0.00..199501.26 rows=9975063 width=1637)
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on new_data  (cost=0.00..99750.63 rows=9975063 width=1637)
              ->  XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..199501.26 rows=9975063 width=1636)
                    ->  XN Seq Scan on existing_data  (cost=0.00..99750.63 rows=9975063 width=1636)
```

Compare with my much uglier `LEFT JOIN`

```
explain
select t1.* from new_data t1 
left outer join existing_data t2 on     
    t1.date = t2.date
    and t1.id1 = t2.id1
    and coalesce(t1.id2, -1) = coalesce(t2.id2, -1)
    and coalesce(t1.id3, -1) = coalesce(t2.id3, -1)
    and coalesce(t1.value, -1) = coalesce(t2.value, -1) 
    and coalesce(t1.attr1, '') = coalesce(t2.attr1, '')
    and coalesce(t1.attr2, '') = coalesce(t2.attr2, '')
    and coalesce(t1.attr3, '') = coalesce(t2.attr3, '')
where t2.id1 is null;

XN Merge Left Join DS_DIST_NONE  (cost=0.00..68706795.68 rows=9975063 width=1637)
  Merge Cond: (("outer".date = "inner".date) AND (("outer".id1)::bigint = "inner".id1))
  Join Filter: (((COALESCE("outer".id2, -1))::bigint = COALESCE("inner".id2, -1::bigint)) AND ((COALESCE("outer".id3, -1))::bigint = COALESCE("inner".id3, -1::bigint)) AND ((COALESCE("outer".value, -1::numeric))::double precision = COALESCE("inner".value, -1::double precision)) AND ((COALESCE("outer".attr1, ''::character varying))::text = (COALESCE("inner".attr1, ''::character varying))::text) AND ((COALESCE("outer".attr2, ''::character varying))::text = (COALESCE("inner".attr2, ''::character varying))::text) AND ((COALESCE("outer".attr3, ''::character varying))::text = (COALESCE("inner".attr3, ''::character varying))::text))
  Filter: ("inner".id1 IS NULL)
  ->  XN Seq Scan on new_data t1  (cost=0.00..99750.63 rows=9975063 width=1637)
  ->  XN Seq Scan on existing_data t2  (cost=0.00..99750.63 rows=9975063 width=1636)
```

The query costs are `1000003266822.61` vs `68706795.68`. I know I'm not supposed to compare across queries but it's proven out in the execution times. Any ideas why an `EXCEPT` statement is so much slower than a `LEFT JOIN` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `left join` is generating a pile of cross joined rows for each (presumably ordered) key value then filtering out the ones it doesn't want via `on`; it can also stop when the (presumably ordered) old key values exceed the new key values since there can't be any more matches--which also involves some inferencing via some `coalesce` SARG smarts. The `except` is sorting everything first. In this case the sorting costs more than generating & throwing away rows, multiply walking through each key's rows of the right hand table. Of course the optimizer *could* include an `outer join` idiom in its `except` planning--but it apparently doesn't.

Related: [PostgreSQL: NOT IN versus EXCEPT performance difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7125291/3404097)